# How to roll out latest .net framework on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

I created a Azure VM (windows sever 2016) using azure portal. It has .net 4.6.2 installed on it. Now I want to roll out latest available .net framework (4.7/ 4.7.1) on it. One option is to download required framework and install it on the VM. I am sure there should be some other better way to roll out .net framework on Azure VMs using Azure portal or ARM template. Please help me with the option available for the same.

Comment: No. A VM is a VM, upgrade your stuff manually or over PowerShell remoting/SSH/pick your poison, but there's nothing Azure specific in this game.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other answer says, you could use Azure Powershell DSC extensión, but there other ways to achieve that.

Usually you dont want the latest versión of the specific app\framework. You want the versión you've tested your app\code against (so its pretty static). You could créate a VM, install all the stuff you need and capture it. You will get an image and from that image you can deploy copies of the VM. That process can be automated with packer (so you dont have to build\recapture manually when\if you want to update something).

Another options is using Azure VM Script Extensión, which is a lot easier than diving into Powershell DSC.

Also, sometimes you could find an image in the gallery that corresponds to your needs (but I doubt that it is the case this time).

Comment: oh yeah, forgot packer

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way in the Azure portal to deploy/upgrade .NET Framework in a VM.  If this was something you were going to be doing a bunch I think you should use PowerShell Desired State Configuration (to install/update .NET Framework) in an Azure Resource Manager (ARM Template).  [This](https://samcogan.com/completing-your-automated-vm-deployments-with-the-dsc-vm-extension/) is a good walk through for what that process would look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Run Command from the Azure Portal to run Start-Process you can get it to run a script from storage to install .net framework.