# How to create an Azure Virtual Machine without the .Net framework installed?

Tags: .net, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, .net-framework-version

I need to test an application using a version earlier than the .Net framework 4.7.2.

How can I create a virtual machine in Azure without the .Net framework 4.7.2 pre-installed or with a earlier version?

The only options I have are Windows 10 and Windows server, both come with the .Net framework 4.7.2 pre-installed.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983737/how-to-roll-out-latest-net-framework-on-azure-vm

Comment: Quick thought - http://woshub.com/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-server-2016/#h2_5 - facilitates backward compatibiliy of 3.x apps.  Will this help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems all the VM images you can choose for your need are all pre-installed with the .Net framework 4.7.2. It means all the built-in VM images in Azure cannot match your requirements. Then you need to create your custom image with uninstalling the .Net framework 4.7.2 and then use the custom image to create a new VM. Or you can uninstall the .Net framework 4.7.2 and use the VM directly. Kindly suggest, if you do not need to create the VM in another time, it's better to use the VM with uninstalling the .Net framework 4.7.2 directly. If the VM needs to be created more times, then the image could be a better choice.

Comment: That is a possibility but I'm not sure how to unistall the .Net framework 4.7.2. How can I do it?

Comment: @illusíon You can try to find `all settings` in Windows 10, then find the apps and uninstall it in the apps.

Comment: @illusíon Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @illusíon Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?